# Could not initialize class org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit

Tags: apache, apache-drill

I can't seem to get Apache Drill to work. I've installed Drill 1.5 on my Windows 7 32-bits based on the official [guide](https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-windows/%22guide%22). I'm on JDK 1.8.0_77

I can start drill without any errors but when I do !list, seems like there are no open connections

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !list  
1 active connection:  
\#0  closed   jdbc:drill:zk=local
```

When I try to read from file, I get a "No Current Connection" message.

When I end by !quit, I also get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:117)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
....
```

I've made the recommended changes to the configuration file (drill-override.conf) according to the guide but still can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-windows/), Drill supports 64bit Windows only.